How to call Share menu item from Shorcuts/applescript/whatever?
There is application (Telegram) which is mostly not scriptable, other than sending keystrokes to it. However, it provides Share menu item for sending messages.
I would like to use this Share menu item from my own automation (Raycast).
It shouldn't be tied to some specific application, so script shouldn't try to find Share menu button, click on it, etc. I'm searching for more generic, application-independent way to trigger Share menu item with provided text from AppleScript/Command line/anything else.
There is 'Share' block for Shortcuts, but it shows all sharing menu and doesn't allow you to specify exact item to call.

Welcome to Ask Different. Why are you looking for a generic solution although you are trying to automate a specific app? You may want to limit the scope of your question to increase the number of answer. Could you share with us what you have tried? That'll help others make useful suggestions.
